# How do I request from a server to execute a specific software on a client

Tags: node.js, websocket, server, client, unreal-engine4

I am trying to create a WebSocket server that runs an update to an Unreal-made software, located inside the clients.

I've been trying to research a way to it, but all I've come across are the development of Real Time Chats.

If anyone can provide something akin to a "Hello World" that executes on the clients side, that would be much appreciated.

Comment: I'm not clear on what you're asking. Any code that you want to run on the client-side needs to be part of the client code. WebSockets can't execute code between the client and server, they just send data back and forth. The client needs to listen for that data and perform its own actions accordingly -- with client-side code.

Comment: Sorry, it seems I wasn't quite clear. What I want is to issue a request to execute a software already present in the client's desktop, from a button click found inside a web browser.

Comment: Unless the node server is running on the client's computer, this isn't possible. Browsers don't have the ability to run executables, for security reasons. The best you can do is trigger a download, like any other download, and let the user decide whether they want to run it or not.

Comment: Is there a way to enable this for certain computers? If not, then how do I, at least issue the executable command from the browser?

Comment: As I said, an executable *cannot* be run from a browser. There are multiple security layers that stop that from happening. The best you can do is provide a download link and let the user decide whether to run it, save it, or just cancel the download. I'm wondering if this may be an XY question after all; why exactly do you think you need to run an executable on the client's computer without letting them decide?

Comment: This executable will use the machines in order to bake many different scenes while everyone is home

Comment: OK... you still haven't explained why you need to run it without first letting the user decide to run it.

Comment: Because no one will be phisically near the User Machines in order to decide whether to run or not.

Comment: In which case, it shouldn't be running. If a user is not even there to be notified that something is downloading, it absolutely shouldn't just be able to run on its own. What you're asking for is a massive breach of security considerations. If you want software that does stuff without the user agreeing, which I think is suspicious at best, malicious at worst, use an application, not a website.